# Android Firebase Admin user Java

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have 3 types of user
parents, teacher, admin,

I have already made login activity 
and for parent and they will provide email and password and when firebase authenticate it. and when successful it will go to parents activity

And i want to make activity for admin to add and register/signup parents
and they still provide email and pass to my login activity and will be directly to the new admin activity after authenticated by firebase

what changes will do to my login

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Button Login;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            // profile activity
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Parent_Home.class));
        }


        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.input_username);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_login).setOnClickListener(this);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_login: {
                userLogin();
                break;
            }

        }


    }


    private void userLogin() {
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            editTextEmail.setError("Email is required");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            editTextEmail.setError("Please enter valid email");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Password is required");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.length()<6 ){
            editTextPassword.setError("Minimum of length of password should be 6");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        //if the email&pass is not empty
        //display dialog
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            progressDialog.show();

            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new 
        OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                //start profile/ menu activity
                                finish();
                                SharedPrefs.saveSharedSetting(Login.this, "CaptainCode", "false");
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Parent_Home.class));
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
    }
}

//Todo: add back confirmation
```

Answer (score 0):

In sign up process add additional object in your database for every user, for example you can call it a `type`. So when someone sign up to your app make him choose which `type` of account he is creating (or maybe you already have this), so object will contain info what account is created: `parent` or `teacher` or `admin`. For example: `type: "teacher"`

After login return data from database for user who just logged in and check what is the `type` of his account and according to `type` value (`parent`, `teacher`, `admin`) you will know who logged in in your app and you can start corresponding screen.